# How to obtain nested object correctly from NgForm?

Tags: json, angular, key-value, ngfor, angularjs-ng-form

I need to obtain keyvalue correctly from ngForm.

I have a User interface in Angular like this:

```
export interface User {
 id: int; 
 name: string; 
 surname: string; 
 school: School;  
}
```

And School interface like this:

```
{
 id: int;
 name: string; 
 address: string; 
}
```

I use *ngFor keyvalue to get key and value and i need to put them inside an <input/> tag like this:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
<div *ngFor="let item of user | keyvalue">
<input ngModel="{{item?.value}}" name="{{item?.key}}" >
</form>
```

when i call in my component myForm.value,for example with console.log(myForm.value), the result is like this :

```
{ 
 id: "someValue"
 name:"someValue" 
 surname: "someValue" 
 school: "[object Object]" 
}
```

but i need it was like this:

```
{ 
 id: "someValue"  
 name:"someValue" 
 surname: "someValue" 
 school: {          
           id:"someValue"           
           name: "someValue"           
           address: "someValue"          
          } 
}
```

How can i access and get correctly those nested key-value in school? Thank you!

Comment: Try: ```<div *ngFor="let item of user | keyvalue | json">```. Moreover have you tried asking chatGPT?

Comment: if i do it, i can't call "{{item?.value}}" and "{{item?.key}}". it gives me error for value: " Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'. Did you mean 'valueOf'? " and for .key: " Property 'key' does not exist on type 'string'."

Comment: omg i asked to chatgpt as you said and i solved...

Answer (score 0):

I asked to chatGPT and it solved it for  me. The solution is binding values with square brackets:

```
<input type="hidden" [ngModel]="item?.value" [name]="item?.key" >
```

Comment: Ask also to chatGPT that how it's possible use an object in an input and what it's the sense to have a form with all the inputs type hidden. Ask also if know the two ways binding `[(ngModel)]`. NOTE: chatGPT can be a marvellous tool if you have a good knowedge but rememebr that the answer can be not correct or not to have sense